# Restarting in TCP mode port 5555 hangs adb

Tags: android, wifi, adb

So I have been following a few tutorials online for setting up android app debugging through wifi, since my USB connection is broken.

The first command line input is giving me problems.

I type in

`adb tcpip 5555`

and get this message:

`Restarting in TCP mode port 5555`

This message just hangs and the process never finishes.

I tried different port numbers, same thing. Tried to connect to my device IP and no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: re-install or update your android-sdk

Comment: are you saying that you do not control the AP you are trying to use? It just might have **client isolation** on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure desktop and device is connected the same network? and

```
1) Switch on wi-fi
2) adb tcpip 5555 - it restarts your device
3) adb connect deviceIpAddress:5555
4) Unplug your device and run project
```

Enjoy the life ))))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, both devices are connected to the same WIFI SSID. My device doesn't restart, this is where the problem lies. Is it possible that the WIFI I'm using is causing the issue. It is a guest wifi I'm connected to.

Comment: _Is it possible that the WIFI I'm using is causing the issue_? Maybe both network should be availabe to each other, I mean _Guest_ network should seesee _desktop network_

Comment: What do you mean when you say desktop network?  Both my laptop and my android device are connected to 'guest-wifi'. Sorry if I'm a bit slow, very new to this.

Answer (score 9):

Just plug out your USB wire at that moment and it will connect.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem sometimes, when that happens, use 5556 or other port. that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

When `adb tcpip 5556` is not responding, remove your data cable and reconnect cable

`adb shell netcfg` - for finding phone ip.
`adb connect ip:5556` the device will be successfully added.
`adb devices` - list all devices connected.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread but it may still help others. My problem solved when I changed my android device usb connection mode from *Usb Mass Storage* to *MTP* inside android usb settings.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue.

in my case i saw there is two cmd opened,
closed another cmd and its worked for me